# Architectural acoustics

Tags: acoustics

I have been asked to solve this exercise.

An environment of $V=1500$ $m^3$, it is considered a reverberated field acoustic pressure level of $70$ $dB$ when an acoustic source of $80$ $dB$ is activated. Compute the total absorption (in $m^2$) in order to obtain a reverberation time of $4$ seconds.

Let me show you my idea: I have to use Sabine's formula $$ T_{60} = \beta \frac{V}{A} \text{  with  } \beta=0.16$$

The surface $A$ should be computed as

$$A = \sum_i a_i S_i $$

where $a_i$ is the absorption coefficient of the $i$-th surface $S_i$.

Can someone help me to find the missing surfaces and coefficients because I can't understand in which way I must find them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [SoundDesign.SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/acoustics)?

Comment: I already asked at soundDesign and they suggested to ask at physics.....that's ok...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I believe it is quite fundamental so I'll try to provide an answer.

The calculation is somewhat straight forward. The total (equivalent) absorption in the room is *A*, so from the first formula one can solve for it, getting

$$T_{60} = \beta \frac{V}{A} \implies A \cdot T_{60} = \beta \cdot V \implies A = \beta \frac{V}{T_{60}}$$

Since you know $\beta$, *V* and $T_{60}$ you can solve for it to get

$$A = \beta \frac{V}{T_{60}} \implies A = 0.16 \frac{1500}{4} \implies A = 60 m^{2}$$

Now, if you would like to get the absorption coefficients you should somehow know the dimensions of the room, or consider uniform distribution of absorption and calculate the coefficient resulting from some combination of  dimensions giving a volume of 1500 $m^{3}$.

Hope this helps somehow.